# Bash - Extract a column from a tsv file whose header matches a given pattern

Tags: regex, bash, csv

I've got a tab-delimited file called `dataTypeA.txt`. It looks something like this:

```
Probe_ID    GSM24652    GSM24653    GSM24654    GSM24655    GSM24656    GSM24657
1007_s_at   1149.82818866431    1156.14191288693    743.515922643437    1219.55564561635    1291.68030259557    1110.83793199643
1053_at 253.507372571459    150.907554200493    181.107054946649    99.0610660103702    147.953428467212    178.841519788697
117_at  157.176825094869    147.807257232552    162.11169957066 248.732378039521    176.808414979907    112.885784025819
121_at  1629.87514240262    1458.34809770171    1397.36209234134    1601.83045996129    1777.53949459116    1256.89054921471
1255_g_at   91.9622298972477    29.644137111864 61.3949774595639    41.2554576367652    78.4403716513328    66.5624213750532
1294_at 313.633291641829    305.907304474766    218.567756319376    335.301256439494    337.349552407502    316.760658896597
1316_at 195.799277107983    163.176402437481    111.887056644528    194.008323756222    211.992656497053    135.013920706472
1320_at 34.5168433158599    19.7928225262233    21.7147425051394    25.3213322300348    22.4410631949167    29.6960283168278
1405_i_at   74.938724593443 24.1084307838881    24.8088845994911    113.28326338746 74.6406975005947    70.016519414531
1431_at 88.5010900723741    21.0652011409692    84.8954961447585    110.017339630928    84.1264201735067    49.8556999547353
1438_at 26.0276274326623    45.5977459152141    31.8633816890024    38.568939176828 43.7048363737468    28.5759163094148
1487_at 1936.80799770498    2049.19167519573    1902.85054762899    2079.84030768241    2088.91036902825    1879.84684705068
1494_f_at   358.11266607978 271.309665853292    340.738488775022    477.953251687206    388.441738062896    329.43505750512
1598_g_at   2908.90515715761    4319.04621682741    2405.62061966298    3450.85255814957    2573.97860992156    2791.38660060659
160020_at   416.089910909237    327.353902186303    385.030831004533    385.199279534446    256.512900212781    217.754025190117
1729_at 43.1079499314469    114.654670657195    133.191500889286    86.4106614983387    122.099426341898    218.536976034472
177_at  75.9653827137444    27.4348937420347    16.5837374743166    50.6758325717831    58.7568500760629    18.8061888366161
1773_at 31.1717741953018    158.225161489953    161.976679771553    139.173486349393    218.572194156366    103.916119454
179_at  1613.72113870554    1563.35465407698    1725.1817757679 1694.82209331327    1535.8108561345 1650.09670894426
```

Let's say I have a variable `col="GSM24655"`. I want to extract the column from dataTypeA.txt that corresponds to this column name.

Additionally, I'd like to put this in a function, where I can just give it a file (i.e. `dataTypeA.txt`), and a column (i.e. `GSM24655`), and it'll return that column.
I'm not very proficient in Bash, so I've been having some trouble with this. I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: if you want to use a tool, then `csvcut` can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below script using `awk` can be used to achieve the objective.

```
col="GSM24655"; 
awk -v column_val="$col" '{ if (NR==1) {val=-1; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i == column_val) {val=i;}}} if(val != -1) print $val} ' dataTypeA.txt
```

Working: Initially, value of `col` is passed to `awk` script using `-v column_val="$col"` . Then the column number is find out. (when `NR==1`, i.e the first row, it iterates through all the fields (`for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)`, awk variable `NF` contains the number of columns) and then compare the value of `column_val` (`if ($i == column_val)`), when a match is found the corresponding column number is found and stored ( `val=i` )). After that, from next row onwards, the values in that column is printed (`print $val`).

If you copy the below code into a file called say `find_column.sh`, you can call `sh find_column.sh GSM24655 dataTypeA.txt` to display the column having value of first parameter (`GSM24655`) in the file named second parameter (`dataTypeA.txt`). `$1` and `$2` are positional parameters. The lines `column=$1` and `file=$2` will assign the input values to the variables.

```
column=$1;
file=$2; 
awk -v column_val="$column" '{ if (NR==1) {val=-1; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i == column_val) {val=i;}}} if(val != -1) print $val} ' $file
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it, and it looks like it works for the most part. I've never really been able to figure out how "awk" works lol. So it's going to take me some to to decipher this. But one thing I noticed was, that if it doesn't find the pattern in the filer header, it prints the entire file, Is there any way to stop this behaviour?

Comment: Also, is there a way for it to print the header as well? Thank you again, for the help. I'm sorry for the multiple questions.

Comment: If there is no field, it won't print anything. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following, it is quick and easy.

In your script, you get the name of the file, let's say $1, and word, $2.

Then, in my for each I am using the whole header, but you can just add a `head -1 $1`, and in the IF, the $2, this is going to output column name.

```
c=0;
for each in `echo "Probe_ID    GSM24652    GSM24653    GSM24654    GSM24655    GSM24656    GSM24657"`;do if [[ $each == "Probe_ID" ]];then 
echo $c;
col=$c; 
else c=$(( c + 1 )); 
fi;
done
```

Right after this, you just do a `cat $1| cut -d$'\t' -f$col`

Answer (score 0):

This also works for printing multiple columns in the specified order:

`tcut(){ awk -F\\t 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)b[$i]=i}{for(i in a)printf"%s"(i==length(a)?RS:FS),$(b[a[i]])}' <(printf %s\\n "$@") -;};tcut GSM24655 Probe_ID<input.tsv`

Or another option is `csvtk -t cut -fGSM24655,Probe_ID input.tsv`. The `-t` flag uses tab as field separator but it doesn't disable CSV-style treatment of double quotes. The `-l` flag (`--lazy-quotes`) allows including unescaped double quotes as part of the data, but it still prints pairs of double quotes around fields that contain double quotes, like `aa"aa` is changed to `""aa"aa""`. `-l` also doesn't disable removing double quotes around fields that don't need to be quoted in CSV, like `"bb"` is changed to `bb`.